# Python manage.py runserver error doing Python Crash Course

Tags: python, django

Trying the python crash course web app project.
`Python manage.py runserver` is throwing off a bunch of errors

> Exception in thread django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call
>   last): File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py",
>   line 917, in _bootstrap_inner self.run() File
>   "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py",
>   line 865, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) File
>   "/Users/me/Pictures/Python/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py",
>   line 54, in wrapper fn(*args, **kwargs

I figured it out actually, but not sure why or how it works, but decided to leave it here in case someone comes across the same problem in the future.

In the `urls.py` file, the textbook tells you to add

```
"url(r'', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace='learning_logs')),"
```

what fixes it is adding this instead of the above,

**`"path('', include('learning_logs.urls'), name='learning_logs'),"`**

```
'''
python manage.py runserver
'''
```

Comment: error code was:
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Pictures/Python/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: You didn't tell us which crash course you're doing. But the reason is that probably your course assumes a prior version of Django (1.8 or 1.11) and you installed the latest (2.2). Your version wants to see a `path` whereas previous versions of Django used `url`. Always check when following a tutorial, which version of python and Django they assume.

Comment: In cases where you figured out the problem but want to leave the solution for others to improve upon or to help others with the same problem consider answering your own question @nick lin.

Comment: Ah, yep. @dirkgroten I think you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved my problem was: using this line instead of the one from the textbook

```
"path('', include('learning_logs.urls'), name='learning_logs'),"
```